# Elements of the file called from post method not accessible in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Please help me. I have a php file that will be called by post method of jQuery. The html elements from this php file cannot be accessible in jquery.
Here comes my code snippet.

In query:

```
var getFinishOptions = $.post("ajax_finish_options.php",
{ event_id: event_name},
  function(data)
  {
   $("#TimeToFinish").append(data);
  }
);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="TimeToFinish">    </div>
```

PHP:

```
<tr style="width: 100%">
    <th style="width: 100%" colspan="2"><?php echo $FinishCategory[0]; ?> </th>
    <th style="width: 100%" colspan="3"><?php echo $FinishCategory[1]; ?> </th>
    <th style="width: 100%" colspan="3"><?php echo $FinishCategory[2]; ?> </th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> Option 1 </td>
    <td> Option 2 </td>
    <td> Option 1 </td>
    <td> Option 2 </td>
    <td> Option 3 </td>
    <td> Option 1 </td>
    <td> Option 2 </td>
    <td> Option 3 </td>
</tr>

<tr>

    <td> <input type="radio" class="FinishOptions" name="FinishOptions" value="<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[0]][$event_id][0]; ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[0]][$event_id][0]; ?> </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" class="FinishOptions" name="FinishOptions" value="<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[0]][$event_id][1]; ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[0]][$event_id][1]; ?> </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" class="FinishOptions" name="FinishOptions" value="<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[1]][$event_id][0]; ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[1]][$event_id][0]; ?> </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" class="FinishOptions" name="FinishOptions" value="<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[1]][$event_id][1]; ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[1]][$event_id][1]; ?> </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" class="FinishOptions" name="FinishOptions" value="<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[1]][$event_id][2]; ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[1]][$event_id][2]; ?> </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" class="FinishOptions" name="FinishOptions" value="<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[2]][$event_id][0]; ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[2]][$event_id][0]; ?> </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" class="FinishOptions" name="FinishOptions" value="<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[2]][$event_id][1]; ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[2]][$event_id][1]; ?> </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" class="FinishOptions" name="FinishOptions" value="<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[2]][$event_id][2]; ?>" />&nbsp;<?php echo $FinishOption[$FinishCategory[2]][$event_id][2]; ?> </td>
</tr>
```

Final piece of jquery:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=FinishOptions]").click(function() {    
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

All i want is, to get the value of any of one checked radio button.

Please give your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cant get the values is that, upon your final piece of jquery, upon execution, you are binding and element which does not yet exist (remember, the radio buttons inside the table are loaded dynamically, thru your ajax call).

Therefore, it will not work. You must use `.on()` in order to catch that after it has been loaded. (its like `.live()`)

Consider this example:

```
// change the final piece of jquery
$('#TimeToFinish').on('click', 'input[type="radio"][name="FinishOptions"]', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```